# Swift: Parsing array elements from JSON request

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting a JSON response from http request. After getting it, it has arrays and trying to parse.

**Swift code:**

```
if let finalResponse = parseJSON["visuals"] as? [String: Any] {


                let balanceResponse = finalResponse ["balanceList"] as? AnyObject
                print("balanceResponse::   \(balanceResponse)")

                let dateResponse = finalResponse ["dateList"] as? AnyObject
                print("dateResponse::   \(dateResponse)")
```

**print log:**

```
balanceResponse::   Optional(<__NSArrayM 0x17404b880>(
{
    data =     (
        "32872.23",
        "38814.87",
        "38915.85"
    );

}
dateResponse::   Optional(<__NSArrayM 0x17005a4f0>(
Apr 26, 2017,
Jun 10, 2017,
Jul 26, 2017
)
```

How to access 3 values in ***data*** array and 3 date values from ***dateResponse***

Comment: Are you using a library like SwiftyJson?

Comment: No, i'm not using,

Answer (score 0):

`dateResponse` and `balanceResponse` will return you a new array. So just treat them as any other array and access the element using index and fill your models.

Other simple way I will recommend you to use third party Library like ObjectMapper or SwiftyJson it will less your work and they are very much stable solutions.

UPDATE:

```
let balanceResponse = finalResponse ["balanceList"] as? AnyObject
let data = balanceResponse[“data”]
let firstValue = data[0]
```

Comment: I could access the second array (dateResponse) as like any other standard array using index, but the first one (balanceResponse) could not able to access like standard array using index.